# How to appy binary mask to NeRF

Tags: binary, mask

I'm confusing becouse this dosn't apply binary mask for NeRF:

```
    def forward(self, x):
        input_pts, input_views = torch.split(x, [self.input_ch, self.input_ch_views], dim=-1)
        h = input_pts
        for i, l in enumerate(self.pts_linears):
            h = self.pts_linears[i](h)
            h = F.relu(h)
            if i in self.skips:
                h = torch.cat([input_pts, h], -1)

        if self.use_viewdirs:
            alpha = self.alpha_linear(h)
            feature = self.feature_linear(h)
            mask = self.mask_linear(h)  # Compute the binary mask
            mask = torch.sigmoid(mask)  # Apply sigmoid activation to get values between 0 and 1

            outputs = torch.cat([mask, alpha], -1)  # Concatenate mask and alpha as the output
        else:
            outputs = self.output_linear(h)

        return outputs
```

I expect:
make changes to the above code to create a binary mask to black what is red in the image and white what is not red in the image. show me exactly where to make changes in the code. print all the updated code in the results. PIL Image